# I want to remove dupplicate rows in array bassed on **TWO** keys

Tags: php

I want to remove dupplicate rows bassed on **TWO** keys 'id_send' and 'id_ip',
I found a function but It can works only with ONE key :

```
function super_unique($array, $key) {
 $temp_array = array();
 foreach ($array as &$v) {
    if (!isset($temp_array[$v[$key]])) {
       $temp_array[$v[$key]] = & $v;
    }
 }
$array = array_values($temp_array);
return $array;
}
```

this is the array 'stats' :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id_send] => 10
        [id_user] => 30
        [id_ip] => 99
        [view] => 9652
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id_send] => 10
        [id_user] => 20
        [id_ip] => 100
        [view] => 450
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [id_send] => 10
        [id_user] => 30
        [id_ip] => 99
        [view] => 456
    )
)
```

So the function I want should returns the 0 and second rows.

Comment: what output you want have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that hard to add a second key to the function arguments like

```
function super_unique($array, $key, $key2) {
```

and then just double the existing logic for the second key

```
if (!isset($temp_array[$v[$key].$v[$key2]])) {
   $temp_array[$v[$key].$v[$key2]] = & $v;
}
```

where that '.' glues values together into a string

Comment: @KarolyHorvath is correct, you can think of something better to identify unique records

Comment: if they are numerical values, just add a space.